# Visualize NetCDF4 file containing burnt area data with QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, netcdf

I've been trying for a while to get QGIS to visualize a ~300 MB .nc file (netCDF4).
Data is burnt area data from here: [Copernicus Global Land Service](https://land.copernicus.vgt.vito.be/PDF/portal/Application.html#Browse;Root=513584;Collection=1000059;Time=NORMAL,NORMAL,-1,,,-1,,).

What I currently do is either drag the nc file to QGIS, after which it imports the 4 layers with the correct names, or <kbd>Layer</kbd> > <kbd>Add layer</kbd> > <kbd>Raster layer</kbd>, which results in the same correct import.

However, I can't find out how I should get QGIS to visualize the data for me. From what I can tell from online sources, the layer should be shown right after you add it. For me it shows this: [image: screenshot of layer not being visualized]

There is no error or anything, it just doesn't seem to visualize my data file. In the bottom right it says `Unknown CRS`, clicking that and setting WGS84 doesn't change it from saying `Unknown CRS`.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? Does the file just have nothing to show? I selected south Portugal in August 2018, when viewing in "quick look" on the Copernicus site there is some burnt area data there.

Comment: In my experience, the .nc files don't display properly. Try to convert to GeoTiff and display. From the command line, use gdal_translate src dest. You may need to set -a_ullr as well.

Comment: I think I have had this problem (i.e. loads with no error but is not displayed) when the file is too large. It doens't seem so large, but if it doesn't work when adding as mesh as suggested below, perhaps try loading just one of the variables and/or small geographical area if you can crop it somewhere else.

Also check the projection of the layer itself is set too.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the netcdf as Mesh layer:
Layer > Add Layer > Add Mesh Layer ...

It should display the temporal component as well. You can manually override the project from Layer Properties.